# Laravel: How to recover deleted folder from vendor directory

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I used composer to get the ***laravelcollective/html*** dependency. But later on I did not need this and I accidentally deleted the folder myself without asking composer to do it for me. Now, whenever I try to run a local server or issue the update command with composer I get the following error:

> [RuntimeException]
>     Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/media/adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directo
>     ry in /media/adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55
>     PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/media/adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/p
>     hp:/usr/share/pear') in /media/adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55

Even though the ***/laravelcollective*** directory does not exist anymore I still get this error. I have tried removing the whole *vendor* folder from my Laravel project and then issued a `composer update` command but I get this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>     Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/media/adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /media/
>     adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>     PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/media/adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share
>     /pear') in /media/adeel/643459A034597650/Projects/Laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem was fixed by issuing the `install` command instead of `update`. I also removed the *composer.lock* file from its directory, but I don't think that made a difference.

Comment: No later on you should _keep_ the .lock file as that is meant to be used to ensure all devs/environments get the same versions of the dependencies. Hence the .lock file should be committed to your versioning system (git, svn)